# Create apps for Hardware Specific only

Tags: android

I want to restrict my app to install on any smartphone. Which means to wanted to specify device hardware validation at the start of the installation only.
e.g. I wanted to install my app only on Samsung device and at all on other device.

**How can we restrict our app to do such hardware specific validation?**

Comment: You certainly can not restrict the installation i think but you can check the manufacturer and Stop app on startup with an alert .

Comment: Thanks @ADM . I have done the same thing programmatically. But still I don't want to waste users time to install app which is not useful for him. And btw this is enterprise app which will not published on play store.

Comment: How important is this to be right?  Because anyone who wants to can fake their device to pretend to be a Samsung.  If this is meant to be a security measure of some sort it shouldn't be relied on as more than a speed bump.  As for worrying about wasted time-  so few people download an enterprise app that its not worth it even if you could.  You've probably already spent more time thinking about it than it would ever save.